# Unable to login after ADFS Certificates rollover

Tags: passport.js, saml, adfs, passport-saml

One of our client had certification rollover at their `adfs` implementation. After that they are no longer able to login.

The main question we are facing is, before this rollover we never used certificates in our saml authentication.

We have set `expressjs` with `passport` `passport-saml` and we never use any `cert` for it. It was working before but now it got stopped.

I searched and found that at our end we need to updated the certificates received from `federationmetadata` from their adfs.

**Questions:**

Any possible reasons why it might have stopped working ? 
How was it working before without certificates if we need to update certificates now ?